# What happens if the ender pearl falls into the Void?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saw that in The End the player begins on an obsidian platform,often in air. To get to the main part,he must throw an ender pearl. But what happens if he misses,and the ender pearl falls into the Void? Will he teleport there and die,or the pearl will be destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Pearl) :

> Ender pearls collide with vines, grass, dead bushes, ferns, flowers, all sapling types, all mushrooms types, all minecart types, boats, and nether portals.

So no dying from throwing it in the void.

Comment: [Here](https://plus.google.com/112695861178921963083/posts/YzP6LUY73SY)  is a less-friendly answer I just found on YouTube (well, Google+, but who cares ?).

Comment: You could have not posted this comment. @Ealhad

Comment: It's not from me, I thought it was kinda funny.